# Parallel.ForEach using Thread.Sleep equivalent

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

So here's the situation: I need to make a call to a web site that starts a search. This search continues for an unknown amount of time, and the only way I know if the search has finished is by periodically querying the website to see if there's a "Download Data" link somewhere on it (it uses some strange ajax call on a javascript timer to check the backend and update the page, I think).

So here's the trick: I have hundreds of items I need to search for, one at a time. So I have some code that looks a little bit like this:

```
var items = getItems();
Parallel.ForEach(items, item =>
{
   startSearch(item);
   var finished = isSearchFinished(item);
   while(finished == false)
   {
      finished = isSearchFinished(item); //<--- How do I delay this action 30 Secs?
   }
   downloadData(item);
}
```

Now, obviously this isn't the real code, because there could be things that cause `isSearchFinished` to always be `false`.

Obvious infinite loop danger aside, how would I correctly keep `isSearchFinished()` from calling over and over and over, but instead call every, say, 30 seconds or 1 minute?

I know `Thread.Sleep()` isn't the right solution, and I think the solution might be accomplished by using `Threading.Timer()` but I'm not very familiar with it, and there are so many threading options that I'm just not sure which to use.

Comment: i don't think you should use `Parallel.ForEach`

Comment: OK what should I use? I'm very open to suggestions.

Comment: So just use a foreach loop with, for example, a task factory?

Comment: maybe this will help - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155756.aspx

Comment: yes, for periodic operations scheduled after a specific length of time, a `Timer` is exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'll be trying these options here soon and will post edits when I figure out what I did for anyone who comes to the question later

Comment: What about startSearch function? Does it starts some `Task`? Maybe it could return task, so you could `.ContinueWith` to it?

Comment: Your concern with using Thread.Sleep is that you'll be pinning one of the thread pool threads? What about using async methods with Task.Delay instead of Tasks?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's quite easy to implement with tasks and `async/await`, as noted by @KevinS in the comments:

```
async Task<ItemData> ProcessItemAsync(Item item)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (await isSearchFinishedAsync(item))
            break;
        await Task.Delay(30 * 1000);
    }
    return await downloadDataAsync(item);
}

// ...

var items = getItems();
var tasks = items.Select(i => ProcessItemAsync(i)).ToArray();
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
var data = tasks.Select(t = > t.Result);
```

This way, you don't block `ThreadPool` threads in vain for what is mostly a bunch of I/O-bound network operations. If you're not familiar with `async/await`, the [`async-await`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/async-await/info) tag wiki might be a good place to start.

I assume you can convert your synchronous methods `isSearchFinished` and `downloadData` to asynchronous versions using something like `HttpClient` for non-blocking HTTP request and returning a `Task<>`. If you are unable to do so, you still can simply wrap them with `Task.Run`, as `await Task.Run(() => isSearchFinished(item))` and `await Task.Run(() => downloadData(item))`. Normally this is not recommended, but as you have hundreds of items, it sill would give you a much better level of concurrency than with `Parallel.ForEach` in this case, because you won't be blocking pool threads for 30s, thanks to asynchronous `Task.Delay`.

Comment: FWIW, `Task.Delay` just uses a `Timer` under the covers.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I'm attempting to implement this right now. I need to keep the current "user" logged in. This system uses cookies as tokens for this. Should I pass around an entire HttpClient object to the different methods, or would you recommend just passing the cookie container?

Comment: @Ryan, neither `HttpClient` nor `CoockieContainer` is documented to be thread safe for concurrent calls. What is the execution environment of your app (GUI, console, Windows service, WCF, ASP.NET, etc)?

Comment: GUI - windows forms. Sorry, I obviously wasn't thinking about the login when I posted, believing that I would be able to use a single instance of WebClient for each parallel thread, eliminating the need to pass cookies, etc. I now realize there are many things wrong with that approach. The flow should go like this: Login, save cookie for subsequent calls, initiate search, check if search is finished periodically, download results. The tokens (as cookies) change at each call.

Comment: @Ryan, a new login per each search, or the login is shared across searches?

Comment: the login could be shared across searches, however, there is no lockout, so if I need to login 100s of times/minute that's OK

Comment: @Ryan, in WinForms, you could use single `HttpClient` with `CoockieContainer` and pass it to each `ProcessItemAsync`. `HttpClient` supports multiple parallel `GetAsync`/`SendAsync`/`PostAsync` requests  (unlike `WebClient`), provided you start them from the same thread. For the code I posted, the thread will be the same if that's WinForms. Just don't use `Task.Run`, you don't need it with `HttpClient`.

Comment: Wow that's great! So I can login once, then use that login token to do all the processing. Thanks!

Comment: @Ryan, yes, under WinFirms you can. `WinFormsSynchronizationContext` makes sure `await` continuations after `Task.Delay` and `HttpClient.GetAsync` will be executed on the same GUI thread (provided that's where you started these tasks). Thus you don't have to worry about thread safety.

Comment: @PeterRitchie, I agree `Task.Delay` is a wrapper around timer. I just think it makes  coding the asynchronous loop logic a bit easier, when used with `await`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also write a generic function using `TaskCompletionSource` and `Threading.Timer` to return a `Task` that becomes complete once a specified retry function succeeds.

```
public static Task RetryAsync(Func<bool> retryFunc, TimeSpan retryInterval)
{
    return RetryAsync(retryFunc, retryInterval, CancellationToken.None);
}

public static Task RetryAsync(Func<bool> retryFunc, TimeSpan retryInterval, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

    cancellationToken.Register(() => tcs.TrySetCanceled());

    var timer = new Timer((state) =>
    {
        var taskCompletionSource = (TaskCompletionSource<object>) state;

        try
        {                   
            if (retryFunc())
            {
                taskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(null);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            taskCompletionSource.TrySetException(ex);
        }
    }, tcs, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0), retryInterval);

    // Once the task is complete, dispose of the timer so it doesn't keep firing. Also captures the timer
    // in a closure so it does not get disposed.
    tcs.Task.ContinueWith(t => timer.Dispose(),
                          CancellationToken.None,
                          TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
                          TaskScheduler.Default);

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

You can then use `RetryAsync` like this:

```
var searchTasks = new List<Task>();

searchTasks.AddRange(items.Select(
        downloadItem => RetryAsync( () => isSearchFinished(downloadItem),  TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))  // retry timout
        .ContinueWith(t => downloadData(downloadItem), 
                      CancellationToken.None, 
                      TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, 
                      TaskScheduler.Default)));

await Task.WhenAll(searchTasks.ToArray());
```

The `ContinueWith` part specifies what you do once the task has completed successfully. In this case it will run your `downloadData` method on a thread pool thread because we specified `TaskScheduler.Default` and the continuation will only execute if the task ran to completion, i.e. it was not canceled and no exception was thrown.

Comment: Thanks Ned. I'm actually going to try to write the same code using this approach and Noseratio's so that I can become more familiar with asynchronous concepts in C#. In particular, I like the use of ContinueWith.