# How to reading out ListView using MultiThreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, listview, items

I want to read out a listview in a form.

My goal is to let the program read the first 3 lines, then it have to sleep some millisecons (Random) and then it has to use the next 3 lines until all listviewitems are used.

I've tried it like this, but the program always checked the whole list after the delay of the first 3 lines.

```
List<Task> Tasklist = new List<Task>();
            List<ListViewItem> lit = new List<ListViewItem>();

int aktuellethreads = 0;
int maximalethreads = 3;

            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                foreach (ListViewItem itt in listView1.Items)
                {
                    lit.Add(itt);
                }
            }));

            foreach (ListViewItem i in lit)
            {
                if (aktuellethreads < maximalethreads)
                {
                    Task t = Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        Random rnd = new Random();
                        Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(300, 10000));
                    });
                    Tasklist.Add(t);
                    aktuellethreads++;
                }
                    if(aktuellethreads >= maximalethreads)
                    {
                    Task.WaitAny(Tasklist.ToArray());
                    aktuellethreads--;
                     }
             }
```

Comment: Give this post a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462525/parallel-foreach-using-thread-sleep-equivalent). ( I cannot comment it due to low rep).

Comment: Well, what does this clearly has to do? Because this code seem to just load all items at once from `listView1` to `lit`, then iterate on `lit` with tasks.
So, in these iterations it will iterate over first 3 items just in the beginning, rest of them will be iterated over if any of the tasks will free, one by one, not in batches of 3.

Comment: Yes, you are right Dominik, but how can i do that it does everytime just 3 items?

Comment: Maybe try WaitAll? After that clean `Tasklist` and `aktuellethreads`.
Well, even no this won't work 100% well, because you take 4-th element just when you are waiting for task finishing.
I'll write proper answer in a minute.

Comment: It does not work well to have multiple threads interacting with the UI. You aren't buying yourself anything by doing this with threading anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it proper you should change your checking approach.

```
List<Task> tasklist = new List<Task>();
List<ListViewItem> lit = new List<ListViewItem>();

int maximalethreads = 3;

this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    foreach (ListViewItem itt in listView1.Items)
    {
        lit.Add(itt);
    }
}));

foreach (ListViewItem i in lit)
{
    Task t = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Thread.Sleep(rnd.Next(300, 10000));
    });
    tasklist.Add(t);

    if(tasklist.Count >= maximalethreads)
    {
        Task.WaitAll(tasklist.ToArray());
        tasklist.Clear();
    }
}
```

It should work, I am not 100% sure of syntax, as I wrote this code in SO answer box, but I think it works.